# Want to change title name while posting my WordPress Site URL when sharing on LinkedIn

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I have created this site in WordPress (https://gs4mc.org/) and installed Yoast SEO Plugin.

I have properly implemented meta and OG tags, but when I am posting the above site URL on LinkedIn, the 'Home_main_latest' dummy title is showing.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

you can use theses meta tags for LinkedIn, you can even set the website title, description or image.

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article'/>
```

here is the reference from [LinkedIn website](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

Also use wp-head wordpress hook to add this code in the website.

Happy Wordpress

Comment: Many thanks for the response but I have already implemented in the site via Yoast Plugin. please have a look:

view-source:https://gs4mc.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please use below URL to get updated title and description from your site in linked share:

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

you have another option apart from the above one: you can add '?latest' after your site URL

Also, please don't forget to include below code in your header file:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article'/>
```

You can use "wp-head" wordpress hook to add this code in the website.
Also, Please install Yoast SEO Plugin in your wordpress site.